# In App Purchases won't allow me to purchase consumable product

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I'm testing out my In App Purchases in sandbox mode and I keep getting the message "This in-app purchaes has already been bought" when I try to purchase it, wherein the product is supposed to be consumable that can be bought unlimited times. I tried kiling my app and restarting it, but it continues to give me this message. Is this an Xcode Objective C bug, or is this an iOS bug? I'd be most grateful for any answers or guidance in resolving this matter, thanks in advance.

Update: Code for SKPayment

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions{
for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions){
    switch(transaction.transactionState){
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchasing");
            //called when the user is in the process of purchasing, do not add any of your own code here.
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            //this is called when the user has successfully purchased the package (Cha-Ching!)
            [self doRemoveAds:validProduct];
            //you can add your code for what you want to happen when the user buys the purchase here, for this tutorial we use removing ads
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Purchased");
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Restored");
            [self doRemoveAds:validProduct];

            //add the same code as you did from SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased here
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            //called when the transaction does not finish
            if(transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled){
                NSLog(@"Transaction state -> Cancelled");
                //the user cancelled the payment ;
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            break;
    }
```

Comment: Which step did you get the message 'This in-app purchaes has already been bought"? Is it returned as the result of `SKProductRequest`, or during the process of `SKPayment`?

Comment: During the process of SKPayment, after I select the buy button when the game asks me "Do you want to purchase GameProduct for 0.99?"

Comment: This usually means you forget to call `[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];` for your last finished transaction.

Comment: I'm gonna add the code for my SKPayment in my question